# How to connect to vercel postgres db in node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vercel

I've recently started using Vercel and have deployed a few simple static pages. I've also experimented with serverless functions and am currently able to return dynamic text content using Node.js. I'm now attempting to use Vercel Postgres for data persistence, but I'm not familiar with any frontend frameworks or TypeScript, and the official Vercel Postgres demo from Vercel is too complex for me. Is it possible to first create a Vercel Postgres database, then use node.js in serverless functions to directly connect to and manipulate this database, and return the fetched database content in response to HTML requests?

Comment: Heroku has a heroku psql command, I am looking for how to do this in Vercel too.  Vercel is using Neon DB.  Maybe need to look at Neon Doc.  I am just not very sure.